# Current GPS location is constantly changing - any smoothing algorithm?

Tags: android, google-maps, location

The location updates (while stationary) still changed - very slightly.
I'm planning on smoothing these updates by comparing the previous location update and only using it if the location has moved by at least 5 metres.

Is there a better (more built in way) to achieve this?

Comment: BTW - These subtle changes in the location updates have been great for testing though - as you can see that location updates are happening !

Comment: There is already a way to set the minimum distance you want to get a new location, take a look at the location API

Comment: Yes you're right ... I'd upgraded to new location API and didn't set this value !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To only get location updates if location has changed by > 10 meters:

```
// 10 meters
mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(10);
```